# MS Access 2007 - Select multiple records and assign a value into a field

Tags: ms-access-2007

I am using a Multiple Items Form to list CASES (records) where there is no TECHNICIAN assigned (Maybe I should use a Datasheet to list the records?).

I would like the user to select a TECHNICIAN from a dropdown field that gets its values from an Employee Table (I can do this). Then I would like the user to select multiple CASES (records) in order to assign that one TECHNICIAN to the Technician field in all of the selected CASES.

Basically, I'm trying to keep the user from having to assign a technician from within each and every incoming case request. I want them to "batch" assign a tech to multiple cases.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I did some more research. This may not be the best answer but it works for now.

1. I created a Multiple Item Form.
2. I added an unbound dropbox that lists Employees from the table
3. I added a button on the detail section (for each record) with the follow line of code:

   Me.Technician = Me.Choose_Technician

Now the user can pick a technician from the dropdown and then click the button to assign that technician to the record/casefile.

This is a simple solution if you only have a couple of records/casefiles to assign. If the amount of incoming casefiles increases there will have to be a way to select multiple records using the shift key. I'll keep researching this.